# String comparison in Powershell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I've the following code in a powershell script:

```
$service = "Letters – Email"

$ss = "`"Letters - Email`""
$ss2 = "`"$service`""

$ss
$ss2

$ss2.CompareTo($ss)
$ss -eq $ss2
```

The output of this is:

```
"Letters - Email"
"Letters – Email"
1
False
```

I don't understand the output. Can you please help?

**EDIT**: I figured out the problem. The hyphen used is different. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Hyphens have bitten me more than once. Especially them [em dash](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=em+dash) that pretends to be a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in you output, The two strings are different:

`$ss`  have a `-`  `[char]45`

`$ss2` have a `-`  `[char]8211`

and the `compareTo` method for `string` returns this:

```
Less than zero 
 This instance is less than strB. 

Zero 
 This instance is equal to strB. 

Greater than zero 
 This instance is greater than strB.

-or- 

strB is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to know more about string.compareTo method.

Comment: Character 45 is a `hyphen`, character 8211 is a so-called `en dash`. They're not just different characters, they also have a different meaning, typographically.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you my english isn't so good to give names to [char] types ;)

Answer (score -1):

Any variables inside double quotes will be expanded to their value, therefore when you assign $ss2 the $service variable is expanded to "Letters – Email" which is why both variables end up the same.

Comment: But the output of the script suggests that they are not equal. Is the expansion only happening when they're written to the console, and ignored for the comparisons?

Comment: @DanPuzey They aren't equals. Read my answer. EDIT: or the question edited :)